# Sorting switches from an array in a grid in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to sort my switches in a grid. The switches are generated from an array so I have no parent/child structure. This is my first time using HTML so I'm unsure how to proceed with this problem. I'm using Arduino IDE with an ESP32.

```
#include "WiFi.h"
#include "ESPAsyncWebSrv.h"

// Set to true to define Relay as Normally Open (NO)
#define RELAY_NO    true

// Set number of relays
#define NUM_RELAYS  15

// Assign each GPIO to a relay
int relayGPIOs[NUM_RELAYS] = {14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 2, 1, 16, 15, 7, 6, 5, 4};

// Replace with your network credentials
const char* ssid = "****";
const char* password = "****";

const char* PARAM_INPUT_1 = "relay";  
const char* PARAM_INPUT_2 = "state";

// Create AsyncWebServer object on port 80
AsyncWebServer server(80);

const char index_html[] PROGMEM = R"rawliteral(
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    html {font-family: Arial; display: inline-block; text-align: center;}
    h2 {font-size: 3.0rem;}
    p {font-size: 3.0rem;}
    body {max-width: 600px; margin:0px auto; padding-bottom: 25px;}
    .switch {position: relative; display: inline-block; width: 120px; height: 68px} 
    .switch input {display: none}
    .slider {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; background-color: #ccc; border-radius: 34px}
    .slider:before {position: absolute; content: ""; height: 52px; width: 52px; left: 8px; bottom: 8px; background-color: #fff; -webkit-transition: .4s; transition: .4s; border-radius: 68px}
    input:checked+.slider {background-color: #2196F3}
    input:checked+.slider:before {-webkit-transform: translateX(52px); -ms-transform: translateX(52px); transform: translateX(52px)}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>S.P.I.T.S.</h2>
  %BUTTONPLACEHOLDER%
<script>function toggleCheckbox(element) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if(element.checked){ xhr.open("GET", "/update?relay="+element.id+"&state=1", true); }
  else { xhr.open("GET", "/update?relay="+element.id+"&state=0", true); }
  xhr.send();
}</script>
</body>
</html>
)rawliteral";

// Replaces placeholder with button section in your web page
String processor(const String& var){
  //Serial.println(var);
  if(var == "BUTTONPLACEHOLDER"){
    String buttons ="";
    for(int i=1; i<=NUM_RELAYS; i++){
      String relayStateValue = relayState(i);
      buttons+= "<h4>Relais #" + String(i) + " - GPIO " + relayGPIOs[i-1] + "</h4><label class=\"switch\"><input type=\"checkbox\" onchange=\"toggleCheckbox(this)\" id=\"" + String(i) + "\" "+ relayStateValue +"><span class=\"slider\"></span></label>";
    }
    return buttons;
  }
  return String();
}

String relayState(int numRelay){
  if(RELAY_NO){
    if(digitalRead(relayGPIOs[numRelay-1])){
      return "";
    }
    else {
      return "checked";
    }
  }
  else {
    if(digitalRead(relayGPIOs[numRelay-1])){
      return "checked";
    }
    else {
      return "";
    }
  }
  return "";
}

void setup(){
  // Serial port for debugging purposes
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Set all relays to off when the program starts - if set to Normally Open (NO), the relay is off when you set the relay to HIGH
  for(int i=1; i<=NUM_RELAYS; i++){
    pinMode(relayGPIOs[i-1], OUTPUT);
    if(RELAY_NO){
      digitalWrite(relayGPIOs[i-1], HIGH);
    }
    else{
      digitalWrite(relayGPIOs[i-1], LOW);
    }
  }
  
  // Connect to Wi-Fi
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }

  // Print ESP32 Local IP Address
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  // Route for root / web page
  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/html", index_html, processor);
  });

  // Send a GET request to <ESP_IP>/update?relay=<inputMessage>&state=<inputMessage2>
  server.on("/update", HTTP_GET, [] (AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    String inputMessage;
    String inputParam;
    String inputMessage2;
    String inputParam2;
    // GET input1 value on <ESP_IP>/update?relay=<inputMessage>
    if (request->hasParam(PARAM_INPUT_1) & request->hasParam(PARAM_INPUT_2)) {
      inputMessage = request->getParam(PARAM_INPUT_1)->value();
      inputParam = PARAM_INPUT_1;
      inputMessage2 = request->getParam(PARAM_INPUT_2)->value();
      inputParam2 = PARAM_INPUT_2;
      if(RELAY_NO){
        Serial.print("NO ");
        digitalWrite(relayGPIOs[inputMessage.toInt()-1], !inputMessage2.toInt());
      }
      else{
        Serial.print("NC ");
        digitalWrite(relayGPIOs[inputMessage.toInt()-1], inputMessage2.toInt());
      }
    }
    else {
      inputMessage = "No message sent";
      inputParam = "none";
    }
    Serial.println(inputMessage + inputMessage2);
    request->send(200, "text/plain", "OK");
  });
  // Start server
  server.begin();
}
  
void loop() {

}
```

This is my output:

[image: Output in browser]

I have tried switching display:inline-block to display:grid, but that results in a page-filled switch. I've tried numerous online tutorials but they all use parent/child structures and that doesn't apply to my code.

Comment: This is not a question about Arduino or ESP32, it is html or css. Even for html, what exactly is your question? or what is the expecting result that you are not able to get?